# Call EJB from another domain

Tags: ejb-3.0, weblogic11g

**What I am doing:**
I'm trying to develop a small prog for calling the EJB from another domain.

**Version**
EJB 3.0
Weblogic 10.3.6

There are 2 domains on Machine1 and Machine2 so the managed servers are
domain1_cluster1_machine1     domain1_cluster1_machine2
domain2_cluster1_machine1     domain2_cluster1_machine2
(hope that I make it clear)

I followed this blog to develop the prog:
http://edwin.baculsoft.com/tag/weblogic/

I deployed the EJB on domain**1**_cluster1_machine1 and domain**1**_cluster1_machine2 with Active status and it can be found in JNDI tree.
Then the client application is deployed on domain**2**_cluster1_machine1 and domain**2**_cluster1_machine2

All of the code is same as the blog, besides the provider url:

```
t3://[IP of Machine1]:[Listen port of domain**1**_cluster1_machine1]
```

When I run the client application from domain**2**_cluster1_machine1, I got the following exception:

> javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is
>   java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to unmarshal class
>   java.lang.Object; nested exception is:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.edw.ejb3.HelloEJBRemote]

When I type wrong in the lookup ie `ic.lookup("com.edw.ejb3.HelloEJBRemote")`, the exception is:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup
>   'com.edw.ejb3.HelloEJBRemote' didn't find subcontext 'com'. Resolved
>   '' [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying
>   to lookup 'com.edw.ejb3.HelloEJBRemote' didn't find subcontext 'com'.
>   Resolved '']; remaining name 'com/edw/ejb3/HelloEJBRemote'

Therefore, can I conclude that the client is able to find the EJB from **domain1** as the exception is not `NameNotFoundException`?

Then what's wrong this it? Is it related to security?

I am newbie of both Weblogic and EJB. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the associated Interface class in the client application? say the `HelloEJBRemote` impl is deployed on cluster1 and its interface `HelloEJBRemote` should part of the deployment of cluster2?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I forgot the interface in cluster2. Thank you! :)

Comment: Based on your comment I'm answering your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Please make sure that you have deployed the EJBs like described below -

> **Cluster 1**

- HelloEJBRemote
- HelloEJBRemoteImpl

> **Cluster 2**

- HelloEJBRemote

Do a look up from `Cluster2` to `Cluster 1` for the Bean using the JNDI name of `HelloEJBRemoteImpl`